# Python numpy and pandas matrix dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have variables that looks like these:

```
data.head()

   Ones  Population   Profit
0     1      6.1101  17.5920
1     1      5.5277   9.1302
2     1      8.5186  13.6620
3     1      7.0032  11.8540
4     1      5.8598   6.8233

X     = data.iloc[:, 0:cols]
y     = data.iloc[:, cols]

X1 = np.matrix(X.values)
y1 = np.matrix(y.values)

X.shape
>>(97, 2)
y.shape
>>(97,)

X1.shape
>>(97, 2)
y1.shape
>>(1, 97)
```

`data` is in pandas frame.

I expected the dimension of y1 would be 97 X 1, but instead it is 1 X 97. Somehow y1 was transposed in the middle, and I don't understand why this is happening. Since my original y panda array was 97 X 1, I thought y1 should be the same too, but apparently thats not how it works

Any explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y.values` converts the column into a numpy array, which has 1 dimension, like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if you call `np.matrix` on that array, it will return

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

However, if you transpose the 1 dimension array into 2 dimension first before you call `np.matrix`, you will get (5, 1) matrix,

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.shape
(5,)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> np.matrix(a).shape
(1, 5)

>>> a.reshape(-1, 1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
>>> np.matrix(a.reshape(-1, 1)).shape
(5, 1)

>>> np.matrix(a.reshape(-1, 1))
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsolicited advice, use of matrix isn't really recommended.  The biggest thing it bought you was operator `*` for matrix multiplication, but with python's 3.5 matmul operator `@` that's not really necessary.

That said, they key thing to note here is that the shape of `y` is not 97 x 1, it is 97, that is a one dimensional array.  A numpy `matrix` is always two dimensional, and simply by convention a 1-d array is a converted into a `1 x X` matrix.